# definition for 'Value' accepting a first argument of type '' could not be found

Tags: c#, wpf

Hi I want to display the selected date from my datetimepicker in a textbox. I have tried the following but get the error on value:  DatePicker does not contain a definition for 'Value' accepting a first argument of type '' could not be found..

```
    private void datePicker_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DateTime date = this.datePicker.Value;

        this.txtExpire.Text = date.ToString("dd-mm-yyyy");

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `DateTime? date = this.datePicker.SelectedDate` instead of Value.

Comment: Thanks, that worked but also get error cannot convert system.dateTime? to system.dateTime'

Comment: pls see the updated answer. SelectedDate is nullable DateTime.

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime date = this.datePicker.SelectedDate;
```

Answer (score 0):

use the SelectedDate property instead of Value...
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datepicker.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to bind textblock to DatePicker use xaml binding:

```
<DatePicker x:Name="DatePicker" />
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=DatePicker, Path=SelectedDate, StringFormat=d}"/>
```